# jQuery slideToggle behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When I am hovering on the basket(#cart_block_top), and without waiting for the end of the animation abruptly remove it from the basket, the animation is still rapidly comes to an end abruptly, and only then it is slide up.
Here is the code:

```
$('#cart_block_top').hover(function() {
    $("#cart_block_slide_content").stop(false, true).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

And here is the link: http://layot.prestatrend.com/
Anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `callback` in order to know when the animation is completed, and invoke

```
$("#cart_block_slide_content").stop(false, true).slideToggle('slow');
```

only when there is no animation in progress.

[Quoting Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/):

> .slideToggle( [duration] [, callback] )
>
> durationA string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> **callbackA function to call once the animation is complete.**

For example:

```
var isAnimationCompleted = true;

function onAnimationCompleted(){
    isAnimationCompleted = true;
}

$('#1').hover(function(){
    if (isAnimationCompleted){
        $("#div").stop(false, true).slideToggle('slow',onAnimationCompleted);
        isAnimationCompleted = false;
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle live example](http://jsfiddle.net/uhdca/2/)

Answer (score 0):

.stop() takes two booleans, first if it should clear queue, here you have false. Second is if it should jumptoend, which you have set as true, so when you stop the function it will jump to the end of the animation. Try this, didn't work perfectly, but looks better.

```
$("#cart_block_slide_content").stop().slideToggle(1000);
```